# Add a publish.htm to vsto clickonce

Tags: .net, clickonce

i have a VSTO Excel Add-in and i need to have clickonce publish.htm page, standartly VSTO add-in's don't have such page(there is no Deployment tab in publish options) can u help me?

Answer (score 2):

When publishing a client application using ClickOnce, you can have it automatically create the publish.htm page for you. This is not an option with a VSTO application, and there's nothing you can do about it. I created my own publish.htm page (one that was actually attractive) and put it on our website. It doesn't show the version number, just a button to install the application. That is about your only choice.

Comment: "you can have it automatically create the publish.htm page" how i can do it, i don't have Deployment tab in publish options, in other projects i have it, in this - i don'y